# How do I customize my Soldier's Emblem?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

In Battlefield 4 Beta you can create and change emblems for your player to use. How do I make them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, log into Battlelog and click on "Soldier" section.
[image]

Next, click on "Customize" and "Emblem" (you can also change Dog Tags here).
[image]

You then get a image editing section. You can create a number of emblems from the shapes and colours shown. I have already had a few (feeble) attempts.
[image]

The User Generated Contents terms state:

> Respect the rights of others. Post only content or links to content that is not defamatory, obscene, offensive or indecent and is comprised of only (1) content or assets from EA games or provided by EA or (2) material that is your own original creation and/or does not violate or infringe the rights of any third party, including without limitation, copyrights, trademarks or trade dress, or rights of publicity/privacy. EA’s Terms of Service apply.

so as images can be reported, be careful.

Comment: Are you supposed to see your emblem on Battlelog? Or only others can see it in game when you kill them? (It did say SAVED and it loads my drawing, but there is no way I can verify it. :/) (The white box on your picture is totally empty for me.)

Comment: @Shiki, yes, should do. I can see my emblem in Battlelog and if I view the profiles of my friends I can see theirs too.

Comment: Okay now I wonder how to fix the issue then. :( I'll try to contact EA (so I can get ignored, lol.) ps.: Thanks!